# How can I display user input from a function into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I'm trying to grab user input from a function and put it into a dataframe using Jupyter Notebook and pandas. This is the closest thing I've gotten so far. I'm trying to do a number generator from a math equation and retaining those results in a variable. Then having those results in that variable put into a dataframe and displayed in rows with columns. It has to be called from a function. Maybe I could save results into a csv then call on that? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
def  main():
    global df
    n = eval(input("How  many  numbers  should  I  print?  "))
    print("This  program  illustrates  a  chaotic  function.") 
    x  =  eval(input("Enter  the first  number  between  0  and  1:  "))
    y  =  eval(input("Enter  the second  number  between  0  and  1:  "))
    for i  in  range(n):
        x = 3.9  *  x  *  ( 1  - x)
        y = 3.9  *  y  *  ( 1  - y)
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns = {"1st Number": [x], "2nd Number": [y]})
        print(df + (x,y))
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The code works, but I was having trouble organizing it and putting it into a pandas dataframe. Below, Khadija reminded me what I was forgetting, an empty list! He put the results of my data into an empty list X = [ ] then, since each iteration output had an x and y result he put them into a zip() function, which iterated each set of tuples in that list. Then pandas was able to figure out how to organize the results I wanted. It was a great solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this one, it works good :

```
def  main():
    global df
    n = int(input("How  many  numbers  should  I  print?  "))
    print("This  program  illustrates  a  chaotic  function.") 
    x  =  float(input("Enter  the first  number  between  0  and  1:  "))
    y  =  float(input("Enter  the second  number  between  0  and  1:  "))
    X = []
    Y = []
    for i  in  range(n):
        x = 3.9  *  x  *  ( 1  - x)
        X.append(x)
        y = 3.9  *  y  *  ( 1  - y)
        Y.append(y)
        df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(X, Y)),
               columns =['1st Number', '2nd Number'])
        
        print(df + (x,y))
```

Comment: This is perfect!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `input` only works in terminal. Jupiter Notebook is based on the web UI, that's why it doesn't work.

In this case you can use the Jupiter Widget for interaction, here is the code sample:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets

def main(n, x, y):
    print((n, x, y))
    # do whatever you want
    
widgets.interact(main, n=widgets.IntSlider(), x=widgets.FloatSlider(min=0, max=1), y=widgets.FloatSlider(min=0, max=1));
```

You may need to install the widget package first if you don't install it before.

More reading: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#